# Wordpress неправильный товар

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

На сайте wordpress установлен плагин woocommerce byoneclick, но при клике на кнопку "купить" у товара, в админке во вкладке byoneclick приходит уведомление с другим товаром. В чём причина?

Comment: Базу трогали руками? Ну там перенос на др хостинг с обработкой дампа?

Comment: нет, только правки контента в админке.

Comment: Этот плагин https://wordpress.org/plugins/buy-one-click-woocommerce/ ? Стоит обратиться к разработчику. но вообще подобное возникает когда проблемы с базой. Напр при неправильной миграции между хостингами. Или др проблемы с БД.